# Can I use decltype without any instance variables?

Tags: c++, decltype

There is a function I'm using from a library that has a macro-ridden output type:

```
STRANGE_MACRO(something) the_function(Type1 t, Type2 u);
```

I would like to define a variable that will take this return value without first declaring a `Type1` or a `Type2`.

I was hoping something like this would work:

```
decltype(the_function(Type1, Type2)) return_value;
```

But it doesn't work. Can I do this without figuring out what the macro evaluates to and without declaring a couple variables first?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is exactly what [`std::declval`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) is for:

```
decltype(the_function(std::declval<Type1>(), std::declval<Type2>())) return_value;
```